# Convex function can be written as supremum of some affine functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Prove that $\phi$ can be written as the supremum of some affine functions $\alpha$, in the sense that $\phi(x) = \sup_\alpha \alpha(x)$ for every $x$, where each $\alpha$ is defined by$$\alpha: x \mapsto a_\alpha x + b_\alpha$$for some $a_\alpha$ and $b_\alpha$.

My progress is as follows. I can show that if $\phi$ is convex and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a real number $c$ such that$$\phi(y) \ge \phi(x) + c(y - x)$$for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

But I am at a loss on how to continue, how to finish. Could aybody help?

Comment: You've shown that $\alpha(y)=\phi(x)+c(y-x)$ is a suitable function to include in your sup, and that furthermore, $\alpha(x)=\phi(x)$.  Now, find some more functions like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\phi$ is convex, for each point $(\alpha, \phi(\alpha))$, there exists an affine function $f_\alpha(x) = a_\alpha x + b_\alpha$ such that

- the line $L_\alpha$ corresponding to $f_\alpha$ passes through $(\alpha, \phi(\alpha))$;
- the graph $\phi$ lies above $L_\alpha$.

Let $A = \{f_\alpha: \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the set of all such functions. We have

- $\sup_{f_\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) \geq f_x(x) = \phi(x)$ because $f_x$ passes through $(x, \phi(x))$;
- $\sup_{f_\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) \leq \phi(x)$ because all $f_\alpha$ lies below $\phi$.

We conclude that $\sup_{f_\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x)= \phi(x)$.

Comment: Could you possibly explain me why there exists an affine function $ f_\alpha$ with the properties you have mentioned in the proof? The rest of the proof is brilliant but I don’t get the beginning. My apologies.

Comment: So $\sup_{f_\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) \geq f_x(x) = \phi(x)$ comes from the fact that $f_x\in A$ and $$\sup(A)\ge\text{ every "element" in }A$$doesn't it? Finally, could you please give me any reference as to the fact that "if $\phi$ is convex, for each point $(\alpha,\phi(\alpha))$, there exists an affine function $f_{\alpha}(x)=a_{\alpha}x+b_{\alpha}$ [...]"?